# Put Google Chrome, AVG on a flash drive

Tags: google-chrome, usb, installation

I often install programs on others' computers such as LibreOffice, which, when they only have a dial-up connection, takes forever to download. So instead I keep it on a flash drive and install it from there. This works fine for LibreOffice.

However, some programs, when you download them all you are downloading is a downloader - when you download `ChromeSetup` and open it, a installer window opens which actually downloads Chrome. Dial-up users then see that it will take 4 hours.

Another example is AVG free antivirus - you download an installer, which when opened actually downloads AVG. However this doesn't work too well for dial-up users.

How do I put the entire program of things like Chrome and AVG on a flash drive for fast installation on others' slow connections?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would highly suggest the [PortableApps Suite](http://portableapps.com/). List of applications avalible can be found [here](http://portableapps.com/apps). If you look around you can often find "offline" installers that have the whole package as a download (i.e. Java as a 20MB package instead of a 700kb download helper).

Comment: "offline installer" - just needed the right terminology and Google got me to this: http://support.google.com/installer/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=126299, faked my user agent as Windows, followed the link, and then it gave me `ChromeStandaloneSetup.exe`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Doing a search for the 'network install' or 'standalone' version of most software packages will give you the installation .exe

Many Network Admins require these installation files to slipstream them into new machine installs or to deploy them company wide using scripts.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to search for offline installers of these programs. Usually there is an optional offline installer.

For chrome you can get one here: https://www.google.com/chrome/eula.html?standalone=1

Avg also has an offline installer: http://free.avg.com/de-de/downloads.prd-afh.line-2012